# How do I enable deep linking from address bar in a Nodejs + AngularJS solution

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, url-rewriting

So I set up a simple NodeJS + ExpressJS server taking care of routing and delivering content for an AngularJS application. It works fine and routing works, but only from within the app. If I type anything in the address bar home.html gets served - which makes sense, since I defined (routing in Node) that anything other than partials should serve home.html.

But how do I make deep linking work then?

When I type in localhost:3000/registrations, localhost:3000/forms gets served. However if I create a link on a page and link to localhost:3000/registrations it works. Also if I type in localhost:3000/registrations in the address bar localhost:3000/forms is served.

**NodeJS+Express server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Set up static directory for serving static html
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/home.html');
});

app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
  var name = req.params.name;
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/partials/' + name);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

//Start server
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server startet on port 3000');
```

**AngularJS app and controller - app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('regApp', [
  'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.
    when('/form/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/form.html',
        controller: 'FormCtrl'
      }).
    when('/forms', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/forms.html',
        controller: 'FormsCtrl'
      }).
    when('/registrations', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/registrations.html',
        controller: 'GridCtrl'
      }).
    otherwise( { redirectTo: "/forms" });
  }]);
```

**Main html - home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="regApp">
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href='/'>
  <title>Registration app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>RegistrationApp</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

  <script src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you route directly you are pointing to the index.html file. #/registration vs /registration.

For further clarification. #/registration is not the same link as /registration. #/registration is actually an anchor link that is passed to angular as a route, where as /registration would try to route to a sub-directory called /registration. If you wanted to you could create that directory and build a new angular app that is specific to registering new users.

Comment: But if someone copies the link from the address bar it wont work, correct?

Comment: @DavidJM sort of - I just accepted that you wouldn't be able to copy the path - however I've seen it working so it annoys me that I haven't found a proper solution - are you experiencing the same problem?